# How to dynamically set element visibility of items in a list view in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a page in Xamarin forms which mimics a table style in HTML. I want the header and data to be able to remove or displayed based on the condition. My problem is I could not figure out a way to access certain property inside the ViewCell of List view.

My XAML code is like this

```
 <Grid x:DataType="models:TransactionHistory" >

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Tran Number"
                   x:Name="LabelTranNumber"
                   IsVisible="{Binding ShowTransactionNumberColumn}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Description"
                   x:Name="LabelDescription"
                   IsVisible="{Binding ShowDescriptionColumn}"/>
            <Label
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Text="Quantity"
                x:Name="LabelQuantity"
                IsVisible="{Binding ShowQuantityColumn}"
                />
            <Label
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Text="Date"
                x:Name="LabelDate"
                IsVisible="{Binding ShowDateRaisedColumn}"/>

            <Label
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="4"
                Text="Extension"
                x:Name="LabelExtension"
                IsVisible="{Binding ShowExtensionColumn}"/>
            <ListView
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding NumberOfVisibleColumns}"
                x:Name="ListViewTransactionHistory">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:History" >
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Text="{Binding TransactionNumber}"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding??? }"/>  --- How do I access ShowTransactionNumber field here?
                                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                <Label

                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Text="{Binding Quantity}" />
                                <Label

                                    Grid.Column="3"
                                    Text="{Binding DateRaised}" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="4"
                                    Text="{Binding FormattedExtension}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

My Model is like this

```
public class TransactionHistory
    {
        public bool ShowTransactionNumberColumn { get; set;  }
        public bool ShowDescriptionColumn { get; set;  }
        public bool ShowQuantityColumn { get; set;  }
        public bool ShowDateRaisedColumn { get; set;  }
        public bool ShowExtensionColumn { get; set;  }

        public int NumberOfVisibleColumns {
            get
            {
                int numberOfVisibleColumns = 0;
                if (ShowTransactionNumberColumn) numberOfVisibleColumns++;
                if (ShowDescriptionColumn) numberOfVisibleColumns++;
                if (ShowQuantityColumn) numberOfVisibleColumns++;
                if (ShowDateRaisedColumn) numberOfVisibleColumns++;
                if (ShowExtensionColumn) numberOfVisibleColumns++;
                return numberOfVisibleColumns;
            }
        }
        public List<History> TransactionHistories { get; set; }
    }
```

My History class is like this

```
    public class History
    {
        public string TransactionNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public string DateRaised { get; set; }
        public decimal Extension { get; set; }

        public string FormattedExtension { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is how do I bind the Transaction History model to view so that my list view is initialised with TransactionHistories. And How can I access the boolean variables inside the cell to toggle visibility of an element inside a cell?

In the code behind I can set the source of list view like this. But I won't be able to access the booleans.

```
ListViewTransactionHistory.ItemsSource = transactionHistory.TransactionHistories;
```

I think I am doing something wrong. Any idea will be helpful. Many Thanks :)

Edit:

On the code behind OnAppearing method I am doing this

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            TransactionHistoryStore transactionHistoryStore = new TransactionHistoryStore();
            TransactionHistory transactionHistory = transactionHistoryStore.GetTransactions();

            if (transactionHistory == null) return;

            LabelTranNumber.IsVisible = transactionHistory.ShowTransactionNumberColumn;
            LabelDescription.IsVisible = transactionHistory.ShowDescriptionColumn;
            LabelDate.IsVisible = transactionHistory.ShowDateRaisedColumn;
            LabelExtension.IsVisible = transactionHistory.ShowExtensionColumn;

            // NumberOfVisibleColumns = numberOfVisibleColumns;
            ListViewTransactionHistory.ItemsSource = transactionHistory.TransactionHistories;
        }
```

So instead of setting IsVisible property manually. How can I bind the transactionHistory variable.

The transactionHistoryVariable is like this

```
public TransactionHistory GetTransactions()
        {
            TransactionHistory transaction = new TransactionHistory
            {
                ShowDescriptionColumn = true,
                ShowQuantityColumn = true,
                ShowDateRaisedColumn = true,
                ShowExtensionColumn = true,
                ShowTransactionNumberColumn = true,
                TransactionHistories = new List<History>
                {
                    new History
                    {
                        DateRaised = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                        Description = "SMITH CHIPS ",
                        Extension = 2.25M,
                        FormattedExtension = 2.25.ToString("C"),
                        Quantity = 2,
                        TransactionNumber = "1234"
                    },
                    new History
                    {
                        DateRaised = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                        Description = "SMITH CHIPS ",
                        Extension = 2.25M,
                        FormattedExtension = 2.25.ToString("C"),
                        Quantity = 2,
                        TransactionNumber = "1234"
                    },
                    new History
                    {
                        DateRaised = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                        Description = "SMITH CHIPS ",
                        Extension = 2.25M,
                        FormattedExtension = 2.25.ToString("C"),
                        Quantity = 2,
                        TransactionNumber = "1234"
                    }
                }
            };

            return transaction;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question.

- In your XAML set up the ListView ItemsSource={Binding TransactionHistories} (Looks like you already set the binding of the page)
- In order you access the page binding, you have to use this small
  binding trick:

1. Set up an x:Name for your parent ContentPage
2. In the element you want to hide, add this: {Binding Source={x:Reference NameOfPage}, Path=BindingContext.NameOfProperty}

More about it [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-path)

Comment: Thanks for the points. This is going to help me change the visibility property. But how do I bind the model to the view? I have updated my question with my data format.

Comment: @JivanBhandari If figured you had already set the page BindingContext, move the code in the OnAppearing override to the constructor of the page. Now inside there write BindingContext = transactionHistory, make sure to only do that if transactionHistory != null. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm for more info on BIndingContext, altho it doesn't look like you are following MvvM principles

Comment: Yes, I am not using MVVM principle. I am sticking with MVC but turns out it's quite confusing.